# How to hide action/share button from QLPreviewController Xamarin iOS 10?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, qlpreviewcontroller

I am subclassing QLPreviewController in my application and using the following code.

```
var pController = new PdfPreviewController();
pController.Datasource = ----

this.MainDelegate.NavigationController.PushViewController(pController ,true);

public class PdfPreviewController: QLPreviewController
{
   public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated){
     base.ViewWillApper(animated);
     this.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem =null;
}

}
```

But with this code, I am not able to hide share/action button which appears at bottom. In iOS 9.X it works perfectly but in 10.X onward this code is broken.  Please help.[image]

Comment: You should probably file a radar on bugreport.apple.com as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 10.X onward & for iPhone u can use`[[self.navigationController toolbar] setHidden:YES];` This is objective C code u can do similar in Your case.I am able to  hide share/action button which appears at bottom using this line of Code.